# How to define Multiple SSL over One IP on Wildfly 8

Tags: ssl, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have a few projects and SSL certificates for each of them but one Ip address. These are running on Wildfly 8 server. I want to use these certificates on one Ip. Based on my research, this is not possible before. But now, it is possible with SNI but I could not find it for Wildfly.

How can I do that with Wildfly?

Comment: At the moment WildFly / Undertow do not support SNI yet but it is on roadmap.

Comment: thanks for command, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770343/ssl-redirection-from-apache-to-wildfly this is how I done it